# Laravel change password reset response

Tags: php, laravel

I'm building an API in Laravel 5.3 and I've to change the default response when a password is being reset.

So how would I do this without making changes to the framework. What I want is this:

In my `ResetPasswords` trait located here `\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetPasswords`

The default response is:

```
/**
     * Get the response for a successful password reset.
     *
     * @param  string  $response
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    protected function sendResetResponse($response)
    {
        return redirect($this->redirectPath())
                            ->with('status', trans($response));
    }

    /**
     * Get the response for a failed password reset.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request
     * @param  string  $response
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    protected function sendResetFailedResponse(Request $request, $response)
    {
        return redirect()->back()
                    ->withInput($request->only('email'))
                    ->withErrors(['email' => trans($response)]);
    }
```

What I want is this:

```
  /**
     * Get the response for a successful password reset.
     *
     * @param  string  $response
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    protected function sendResetResponse($response)
    {
        return response()->json(['success' => trans($response)]);
    }

    /**
     * Get the response for a failed password reset.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request
     * @param  string  $response
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    protected function sendResetFailedResponse(Request $request, $response)
    {
        return response()->json(['error' => trans($response)], 401);
    }
```

So how can I accomplish that without making changes to the framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the methods in your second codeblock to your **ResetPasswordController**. This will override the Trait's methods in the controller using it.

By doing so you are not making changes to the Laravel framework and your changes won't be lost on a next composer install.